# Should I hyphenate "up-to-the-minute" in this case?

Tags: sentence, hyphenation

I have had a look at some examples on here, but I am still not sure. Should I hyphenate "up-to-the-minute" in this sentence?

> We can supply you with up-to-the-minute intelligence on distributors, companies and geographical locations, allowing you to make an informed decision.

OR

> We can supply you with up to the minute intelligence on distributors, companies and geographical locations, allowing you to make an informed decision.

I am leaning toward hyphenating as it is an adjective for *intelligence*, and also a longer sentence so possibly misread, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is not absolutely necessary, but I think this is one of the easier calls with hyphenation; adding clarity in combining the entire adjective into one unit, and matching quite a few dictionaries (most have it either as hyphenated or as both with hyphens predominant among the cited examples).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, hyphenate the words of a *phrase* that modifies a noun.; in your example, "up-to the-minute" is an adjectival phrase that modifies "intelligence."

Note that this hyphenation rule doesn't apply to adverbs within an adjectival phrase, such as "recently received intelligence."